# php imap support error

Tags: php, centos, imap, centos7

i wish install php with imap support (--with-imap) but i get this error.

```
checking for U8T_DECOMPOSE...
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is 
missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.
```

the version php it is 5.6.24 (on Centos7 64) and command run it is

```
 ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-sockets  --with-snmp --enable-mbstring --with-curl --with-gd --with-mysqli --with-imap


 yum install libc-client.x86_64
Package libc-client-2007f-4.el7.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the packages published for CentOS also offer the php-imap module. Why do you want to compile that yourself?

Comment: i wish install osticket, imap it's a requeriment. the module php-imap this installed.

Comment: If php-imap is installed, then again the question: why do you want to compile php?

Comment: I need to install osTicket and within the requirements or optional imap support this, so I need to compile php with imap support. I hope you understand.

Comment: Well, I do understand that you want to install `osTickets` (whatever that is) which apparently requires imap support in php. That is exactly what is offered by the php-imap module. So why don't you simply install that module from the repositories and all is fine? Absolutely no need to compile in my eyes. But maybe I miss quite a lot here. Might be. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: yes, compile without support php imap, thanks anyway for your help.